# Applying a pandas GroupBy with mixed boolean and numerical values

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

How can I apply a pandas groupby to columns that are numerical and boolean? I want to sum over the numerical columns and I want the aggregation of the boolean values to be `any`, that is True if there are any Trues and False if there are only False.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a `sum` aggregation will give the desired result as long as you cast the boolean columns back to boolean types.  Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
 'bool': [True, False, True, True, False, False],
 'c': [10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 20]})

       id   bool   c
    0   1   True  10
    1   1  False  10
    2   2   True  15
    3   2   True  15
    4   3  False  20
    5   3  False  20

    df.groupby('id').sum()
        bool   c
    id          
    1    1.0  20
    2    2.0  30
    3    0.0  40
```

As you can see when applying the sum True is cast as 1 and False is cast as zero. This effectively acts as the desired `any` operation. Casting back to boolean:

```
df['bool'] = df['bool'].astype(bool)

   id   bool   c
0   1   True  10
1   1  False  10
2   2   True  15
3   2   True  15
4   3  False  20
5   3  False  20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the functions which you aggregate by with the following:

```
df.groupby("id").agg({
    "bool":lambda arr: any(arr),
    "c":sum,
    })
```